# Segmentation fault when trying to concatenate an element of a 2d array

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strcat

I wanted to use `strcat()` to concatenate an element of an array of strings. I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char **str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    }

    str[0] = "foo";
    str[1] = "bar";

    strcat(str[0], "H");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

and I get the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What should I do to get it right?

Comment: The `str[0] = "foo"; str[1] = "bar";` overwrites the memory allocation pointers, and you consequently try to concatenate to a string literal: so a segfault. Use `strcpy()` to copy a string.

Comment: One note: you `free` `str` but not the 8 bytes of memory each of those three pointers points to. Given that this in main and it's a tiny amount of memory, this is probably not a practical concern, but it's good to get into good habits wrt memory management.

Comment: The `printf("%s\n", str[2]);` will be undefined behaviour as the allocated memory doesn't contain a string.

Comment: Or to add to what @WeatherVane suggested, you may wish to use `strncpy` to _ensure_ you don't have a buffer overflow. Again, not a practical concern here, but good habits...

Comment: Note that strictly this isn't a "2d array" but a "jagged array" or "array of arrays".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the program has memory leaks. At first memory was allocated and its addresses were stored in pointers str[i]

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
}
```

and then the pointers str[0] and str[1] were reassigned by addresses of string literals.

```
str[0] = "foo";
str[1] = "bar";
```

As a result you may not change a string literal by this statement

```
strcat(str[0], "H");
```

because this invokes undefined behavior

You have to write

```
strcpy( str[0], "foo" );
strcpy( str[1], "bar" );
```

And this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", str[i]);
}
```

also invokes undefined behavior because the element str[2] was not initialized by a string.

Either you need to change the condition or the loop like `i < 2` or to initialize the element str[2].

And you need to free all the allocated memory like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    free( str[i] );
}

free( str );
```